# libXML error retrieving children - not returning content of further children

Tags: c, xml, libxml2

OK, i've been going round in circles with this one. I'm trying to parse an XML file / data into some structs.

Because every child element requires certain business logic to be carried out, I have decided to create separate procedures to manage each child element.

The original xml can be found here: http://hearme.fm/ars.xml

I can manage the DAAST element, this then feeds through to the Ad element, but when I try to get into the Inline element. node->name returns: "Text" and I can't seem to get any further than this.

Can anyone shed any light?

Thanks

```
#ifndef DAASTXML_C_
#define DAASTXML_C_

#define XMLSTR(str) ((xmlChar *)(str))

#include "daastXML.h"
#include <libxml/xmlmemory.h>
#include <libxml/parser.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void parseAds(xmlDocPtr doc, xmlNodePtr node, struct daastXML xmlFile);
void parseInline(xmlDocPtr doc, xmlNodePtr node, struct daastXML xmlFile);
void parseCreatives(xmlDocPtr doc, xmlNodePtr node, struct daastXML xmlFile);

void daastParser (char *filePath){

    xmlDocPtr doc;
    xmlNodePtr node;

    doc = xmlParseFile(filePath);
    node = xmlDocGetRootElement(doc);

    struct daastXML xmlFile;

    if (xmlStrcmp (node->name, XMLSTR("DAAST")) == 0){
        xmlFile.version = (char *)xmlGetProp(node, XMLSTR("version"));

        parseAds(doc, node->children, xmlFile);

    }
    xmlFreeDoc(doc);

}

void parseAds(xmlDocPtr doc, xmlNodePtr node, struct daastXML xmlFile){

    vectorAds_init(&xmlFile.Ads);

    do {
        if (node == NULL) break;
        if (xmlIsBlankNode(node)) continue;

        if (xmlStrcmp (node->name, XMLSTR("Ad")) == 0) {

            struct daastAd newAd;
            newAd.id = (char *)xmlGetProp(node, XMLSTR("id"));
            newAd.sequence = (char *)xmlGetProp(node, XMLSTR("sequence"));

            // At this point we need to get the inline (or wrapper) info *** WRAPPER NOT INTEGRATED ***
            printf("\nAdvert ");
            printf("\n");

            parseInline (doc, node->children, xmlFile);

            vectorAds_append(&xmlFile.Ads, newAd);
        }
    } while ((node = node->next));
}

void parseInline (xmlDocPtr doc, xmlNodePtr node, struct daastXML xmlFile){

    printf("\nInline : node name: ");
    printf(node->name);

    if (xmlStrcmp (node->name, XMLSTR("InLine")) == 0){
        printf("We've got the inline element");
    }

    parseCreatives (doc, node->children, xmlFile);
}

void parseCreatives(xmlDocPtr doc, xmlNodePtr node, struct daastXML xmlFile){

    printf("\nCreatives \n");

}
```

Comment: You need to check the node type. Use `if (node->type == XML_ELEMENT_NODE) `.

Comment: @kaylum - it seems that the type is a text node, and not an element (like the previous node). How do I go about retrieving the sub values on this basis?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that I've found answer, with the help of @kaylum.

I've added the following:

I've added this routine to the parseInline process, and seems to work now

```
do {
    if (node->type == XML_ELEMENT_NODE){
        printf(node->name);
        break;
    }
} while((node = node->next));
```

i.e. it loops through all of the children for the parent, and I can operate on the node when it returns an Element_Node.